# React, Graphql - useMutation to delete from DB

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm trying tok create a simple demo CRUD app using React and Graphql

I have the backend all set and working.

On the front end I'm using React with useQuery and useMutation.

I have the create working with useMutation to create the data and the read with useQuery to show the data.

I now stuck with the delete. I have a button the post and I can get the id of the post to pass to the useMutation function to delete the post.

I'm just stuck getting it to work if anyon can help.

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { RecipeData } from '../generated/RecipeData';
import { GET_ALL_RECIPES, ADD_RECIPE, DELETE_RECIPE } from '../queries';
import { useQuery, useMutation } from 'react-apollo-hooks';


const App: React.FC = () => {

  const [name, setName] = useState<string>('')
  const [description, setDes] = useState<string>('')
  const [id, setId] = useState<string>('')

  const handleNameChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setName(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleDesChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setDes(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    createRecipe()
  };

  const handelDelete = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setId(e.target.parentElement.getAttribute("data-id"))
    deleteRecipe()
  }

  const [deleteRecipe] = useMutation(DELETE_RECIPE, {
    variables: { id }, refetchQueries: ['RecipeData']
  })

  const [createRecipe, { error }] = useMutation(ADD_RECIPE, {
    variables: { name, description }, refetchQueries: ['RecipeData']
  })
  if (error) {
    console.error('erroring : ', error)
  }

  const { data, loading } = useQuery<RecipeData | null>(GET_ALL_RECIPES, {
    suspend: false
  })

  if (loading || !data) return <div>Loading</div>

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Graphql</h1>
      <ul>
        {
          data.recipe !== null && data.recipe.map((recipe, i) => (
            <li key={recipe._id} data-id={recipe._id}>
              {recipe.name}
              <button onClick={handelDelete}>X</button>
            </li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>

      <form>
        <div>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={name}
            onChange={handleNameChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Description</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={description}
            onChange={handleDesChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Recipe</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

queries/index.tsx

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

export const GET_ALL_RECIPES = gql`
  query RecipeData{
    recipe{
      _id
      name
      description
    }
  }
`
export const ADD_RECIPE = gql`
  mutation addRecipe($name: String!, $description:String){
    addRecipe(name: $name, description: $description){
      _id
      name
      description
    }
  }
`

export const DELETE_RECIPE = gql`
  mutation deleteRecipe($id: Int!){
    deleteRecipe(_id: $id){
      _id
      name
      description
    }
  }
`
```

Server side

schema.js

```
exports.typeDefs = `

  type Recipe{
    _id: ID
    name: String
    description: String
  }

  type Query{
    recipe:[Recipe]
  }

  type Mutation{
    addRecipe(name: String!, description: String):Recipe
    deleteRecipe(_id: Int):Recipe
  }

`
```

resolvers.js

```
exports.resolvers = {

  Query:{
    recipe: async(obj, args, {Recipe}, info) => {
      const allRecipes = await Recipe.find()
      return allRecipes
    }
  },
  Mutation:{
    addRecipe: async(obj, {name, description}, {Recipe}, info) => {
      const newRecipe = await new Recipe({
        name,
        description
      }).save()
      return newRecipe
    },
    deleteRecipe: async(obj, args, {Recipe}, info, {_id}) => {
      delete Recipe[_id];
    }
  }

}
```

I don't have a live demo sorry but this outputs a list of recipe name with an input field to add new recipes, this part works.

I also have a delete button after each recipe displayed. I wanted to click this button and have that recipe be removed from the list.

At the moment when I click this delete button I get the following error message in the network tab of the dev tools

`message: "Variable "$id" got invalid value ""; Expected type Int. Int cannot represent non-integer value: """`

Comment: First thing I can see is that your mutation requires an integer (ID) but you're passing a string to it. `const [id, setId] = useState<string>('')` eventually ends up at `mutation deleteRecipe($id: Int!){...`

Comment: Saying you're stuck isn't particularly helpful. What's the expected behavior -- and what behavior are you seeing instead? Are there any errors in the console when the unexpected behavior occurs-- if so, what are they? If you look in dev tools, is your request actually being sent -- if so, is it coming back with the expected response?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question with more information now

Answer (score 0):

```
const handelDelete = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
  setId(e.target.parentElement.getAttribute("data-id"))
  deleteRecipe()
}
```

`setID()` is needed for something (other than passing parameter) ?

`id` is not updated immediately by `setID()` (async updates like `setState` - see docs) - value can't be used in following `deleteRecipe()`

IMHO there should be:

```
const handelDelete = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
  const delID = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute("data-id")
  deleteRecipe( delID )
}
```

and deleting with direct parameter passing:

```
const deleteRecipe = (id) =>  useMutation(DELETE_RECIPE, { 
  variables: { id }, refetchQueries: ['RecipeData']
})
```